# Toolbar not showing in UIView

Tags: iphone

I am having different views in one Xib file and am moving from one to the next and back. All views have a button that should reveal the same toolbar which I added in IB in its own view. Only when the toolbar gets called it is always behind the view. How do I get it to show on top of the view?

Answer (score 0):

try creating a containing view (maybe a vertical scrolling UIScrollView if you have more content than can be displayed) and move your existing views in and out if that content view. That way the base structure of you view doesnt change, you are just changing what is in the containing view.

Or make the containing view a horizontal UIScrollView (if you dont have more content than can be displayed on one view) and just set the content offset for whatever view you need, this will give you a nice animated switching, just dont load all of the extra views into the scrollview if there are more than 3 or so, do that programmatically with the UIScrollView delegate.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion but what I really want is to call the same toolbar from different subviews.

Comment: yes, the suggestion above would all be contained in the same xib/viewcontroller and allow you to have access to multiple views that would be programmatically put into a containing view that is manually positioned above or below your toolbar.